# How to format the output of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to format the values of a dictionary in python. Here is the script that i have used to generate the output

```
entries = {}
entries1 = {}

with open('no_dup.txt', 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        if line.startswith('E'):
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split()
            entry = line[0]
            if entry in entries:
                entries[entry].append(line)
            else:
                entries[entry] = [line]

with open('no_dup_out.txt', 'w') as fh_out:
    for kee, val in entries.iteritems():
        if len(val) == 1:
            fh_out.write("{} \n".format(val))


with open('no_dup_out.txt', 'r') as fh_in2:
    for line in fh_in2:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        entry = line[1]
        if entry in entries1:
            entries1[entry].append(line)
        else:
            entries1[entry] = [line]


with open('no_dup_out_final.txt', 'w') as fh_out2:
    for kee, val in entries1.iteritems():
        if len(val) == 1:
            fh_out2.write("{} \n".format(val))
```

For example by running the above script i generated the following output

```
[["[['ENSGMOG00000003747',", "'ENSORLG00000006947']]"]] 
[["[['ENSGMOG00000003752',", "'ENSORLG00000005385']]"]] 
[["[['ENSGMOG00000003760',", "'ENSORLG00000005379']]"]] 
[["[['ENSGMOG00000003748',", "'ENSORLG00000004636']]"]] 
[["[['ENSGMOG00000003761',", "'ENSORLG00000005382']]"]]
```

And i would like to format it such as way that i remove all the parentheses and commas (`ENSGMOG00000003747 ENSORLG00000006947`) and output the rest as it is using tab delimited format. How can i do that?

Comment: Is this the format you finally expect? (ENSGMOG00000003747 ENSORLG00000006947)  ?

Comment: Yes and so on for all the other lines

Comment: Wait, you have a dictionary, containing lists, which contain lists, containing strings, containing characters that indicate lists in lists and strings? I recommend [taking a step back and parsing your input data properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You've done something wrong to get your data into this format. While we could tell you something to do that would get your data from this format to something sane, the resulting program would be akin to a car factory that welds the engine to the roof, then painstakingly undoes the welds and attaches it in the correct spot.

Comment: I have now added the script that i have used to generate that kind of ouput

Answer (score 0):

If your list of lists is `full_list`, then you could have the following code give your desired output:

```
desired_list = ['\t'.join([element.split('\'')[1] for element in list_item[0]]) for list_item in full_list]
```